# restoring a failed SBS 2000 box

Tags: windows, configuration, hardware, windows-sbs

I read a post where you had mentioned you have had a PERC card blow up on you in an SBS box...  I've got a similar situation where one of my RAID drives failed and then the power supply failed before I could replace the drive...  I then replaced the power supply and the failed drive and reconfigured the RAID array. I had a recent full backup of the my Win2k SBS's C: drive stored on my SYmantec backup exec server so I installed win2K server on the c: partition and then once I had that up and running, installed the backup exec agent so as to do a restore of the entire c drive including system state. THis all worked just fine, until I had to reboot. I received an "incorrect drive configuration" error and then it hangs.  I figure that likely makes sense becasue I think my RAID array is configured slightly different now in that the partitions may be sizeded ever so slightly differently now than they were before I think...

Is there a way I can just restore from my backup BUT maybe exclude some of the registry and hidden boot files it wants to restore so that it is booting with the current configuration now active on that machine - not the pre blow up configuration files?

I also read a post that indicated you might have to install the exact same service pack etc... etc.. before attemting a restore but that does not make sense to me being as the entire c drive contents are going to be overwritten by the restore anyway? THe basic OS install is just to be able to get the backup exec agent installed . I can;t understand why one would need to install the exact same SP level.

Can you shed some light on what I might be able to do to get this thing up and running?

Comment: Welcome to Serverfault, Brad! Who do you mean by "you"? I guess you copied the text from an email you wrote. You can edit your question making your point clearer. Thanks!

Comment: Depending on how critical this is, you may want to call Symantec or Dell and pay for support so that you can get this server up (if you're running SBS 2000 I'm guessing the hardware is out of warranty). There's a time to figure out a problem as you go along and a time to pay someone who knows more than you to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I never had great luck with 3rd party backup software (CA ArcServe or BackupExec) restoring the system state and/or entire system drive on SBS.  Unfortunately, even with these tools system state (registry, Active Directory, etc.) is pretty much an all-or-nothing proposition.  That said, the disk error could be from your backup itself if it was taken after the array began to degrade or fail.  I would give it another try after installing the correct service pack level, and barring that I'd try an older backup.  The last other option is to recreate the entire domain from scratch.  With SBS this is less of a disaster than if you had 100s or 1000s of users, but can still obviously be quite a PITA.

I had better luck creating batch files that ran ntbackup, exmerge.exe, and osql jobs separately to back up files/system state, brick-level email mailboxes, and SQL databases respectively.  It seemed to have a better chance of restoring system state without malfunction, and separating these resulted in more flexible and discreet backups.